# How do I avoid getting out-of-memory errors when compiling TouchDB for Android?

Tags: android, couchdb, touchdb

I'm trying to use [TouchDB for Android](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android) but when I try to compile the sample project or make one myself, it says it couldn't compile the dex because it ran out of memory or exceeded the heap size. Then Eclipse crashes, yada yada yada I end up waiting 10 minutes every time I try to change something to fix the issue.

I've got a pretty generous heap size set, and TouchDB isn't a huge project. So I think that I must be missing some critical bit of the puzzle.

Has anybody else had this problem and found a solution? I'm using Eclipse (version Juno) on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start eclipse with parameters  -vmargs -Xmx1024M

Comment: I thought that this was going to be an issue with the dex compiler based on the error message, but I guess I was wrong! I don't totally understand how setting eclipse's max vm memory fixed the issue if the error occurred while dexing (since this is a different process), perhaps dex fails due to an Eclipse failure. Anyway, thanks :)